# How to type hindi font with texmaker and miktex?

Tags: fonts, xetex, miktex, texmaker, unicode

trying to type hindi font using Texmaker with Miktex. The hindi typing is done using hindi google input tools installed in the system. Please help in this regard.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial Unicode MS}
\begin{document}
मेरा नाम सौरभ है|
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue here is the font you use. In Windows [you should have](http://gsesoftsolutions.com/how-to-download-hindi-fonts-and-type-in-microsoft-word/) `Mangal` font installed, but I have [downloaded](http://hindi.changathi.com/Fonts.aspx) and installed `Akshar Unicode` and it worked just fine.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Akshar Unicode}
\begin{document}
मेरा नाम सौरभ है|
\end{document}
```

This is the output from `xelatex`:

[image: Hindi]

Comment: Thank you very much, I appreciate your help. It is working fine.